# Spotfire connection to mysql?

Tags: mysql, spotfire, data-connections

I am trying to find a way to connect to mysql database with spotfire but I can only find the connector for sql server and oracle. I am using spotfire cloud. If someone can help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the connector you need.](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

[Here is the installation instructions.](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spc/7.6.1/doc/pdf/TIB_spc_7.6.1_installation.pdf)

Depending on your version, [you may find this reference useful](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_connector_for_oracle_mysql/3.0.0/doc/pdf/TIB_spc-oraclemsql_InstallationManual.pdf), though it'd dated.

Comment: Thanks, I also find informations for the 7.6 cloud version: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-data-access